# Opening documents with office online and Office 16 versions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, document, sharepoint-library

In SharePoint Document Library: when I open a document in Office 2016, it loses its Headers and formatting if it was created in an earlier version of Office.  When it opens in Office online, it looks fine.  Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Office, not SharePoint. What do you mean by "earlier version"? Does 2013 to 2016 cause the problem? Or only 2003 (xls) to 2016 (xlsx) cause the problem? Have you tried downloading the document first as a file, then opening with Office?